# .NET Standard and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I've installed recently released Visual Studio 2017 and created a .NET Standard Class Library project.
The `.cproj` just targets .NET Standard v1.4:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Within Visual Studio, it states that it successfully referenced the NETStandard.Library metapackage.

Within this library project, I have a simple class that utilizes `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` type.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public Class1(Action action)
        {
            var task1 = Task.Run(action);
        }
    }
}
```

During the build in Visual Studio it does check compatibility with .NETStandard 1.4 against the dll-s found in nuget packages, however those dll-s are not copied to the output folder.

> Checking compatibility for System.Threading 4.3.0 with
>   .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
>
> 1>            System.Threading.Tasks/4.3.0 1>
>   Name=System.Threading.Tasks 1>
>   Path=system.threading.tasks/4.3.0 1>
>   ResolvedPath=C:\Users\user-name\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks\4.3.0
>   1>                    Type=package 1>                    Version=4.3.0

The project compiles and produces dll (ClassLibrary1.dll) referencing only 2 assemblies: System.Runtime.dll and System.Threading.Tasks.dll.

Which are resolved to GAC dlls:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.dll
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Threading.Tasks.dll

These are the Full .NET Framework 4.6.1586.0 assemblies, installed globally in my Windows and registered in GAC.

**QUESTION: Is this a correct behavior?** After reading the .NET Standard docs I was convinced that ClassLibrary1.dll would reference netstandard.dll which would act as a facade for nuget versions of System.Runtime.dll and System.Threading.Tasks.dll. And/or those dll-s would be copied into output directory along with ClassLibrary1.dll.